# How to create make this layout responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm new to web development, and I'm trying to make a static responsive website.

So far, I was able to make a responsive navigation bar, but I'm stuck at how to make this layout.

[image: Desktop]

This layout on mobile should look like this:

[image: Mobile]

So far, I've found this code on the bootstrap website, and it resizes images depending on the browser's width.

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="...">
```

However, I don't know how to add text near the "image". If I put "image" and "text" in the same div, the code above acts weirdly. The image doesn't resize immediately. It looks like the div's size changes and then the image's size changes depending on that.

Can anyone help me to make this layout?

Comment: Use CSS flexbox + the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

Comment: Could you put together an example of the HTML and CSS you're working with? It should help get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to work better with the DIVs to get the result you want. Imagine that the divs is like organizers boxes and you don't want to mess up with the things inside.
You can do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="https://cdn.auth0.com/blog/new-bootstrap4/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning">
      <p>empty text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="https://itriangletechnolabs.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/bootstrap-illustration.png" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="https://socpub.com/sites/default/files/images-2018/Bootstrap.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="..."> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjohnatha/L34gb05r/1/ (just remember to resize the splitted window to get it responsive)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the code. That actually helped me to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

just add the bootstrap class accordingly :

```
total 12 columns in page so you have to divide accordingly 

mobile device use class : "col-xs-6" or "col-xs-12"// according to requirement
Small device use class : "col-sm-6" or "col-sm-12"
medium device use class : "col-md-6" or "col-md-12"
large device use class : "col-lg-6" or "col-lg-12"

<div class ="col-sm-6"> 
<img src="" />
</div>

<div class ="col-sm-6"> 
//text
</div>
```

// for leave blank space use "col-sm-offset-6" so it will leave half container blank and element in other half.